How to automatically add custom grains attributes to minions using SaltStack Reactor?
I want to automatically add grains attributes to a minion when it authenticates or starts. I have added the following configuration to the reactor configuration file:
reactor:
  - 'salt/auth':
    - /srv/salt/reactor/grains_add.sls
  - 'salt/minion/*/start':
    - /srv/salt/reactor/grains_add.sls


The grains_add.sls file contains the following:
add_custom_grains:
  local.grains.setvals:
    - tgt: {{ data['id'] }}
    - arg: 
      - {"code":"2","code_ename":"tt"}


This approach hardcodes the values. I want to set the grains attributes by retrieving the code variable from the minion's pillar data. Based on the official documentation, I tried using an orchestrate runner, and rewrote the grains_add.sls file as follows:
invoke_orchestrate_file:
  runner.state.orchestrate:
    - args:
        - mods: orchestrate.add_granis
        - pillar:
            minion_id: {{ data['id'] }}       


The orchestrate.add_granis file contains the following:
{% set minion_id = salt.pillar.get('minion_id') %}
get_grains:
  local.grains.item:
    - tgt: {{ minion_id }}
    - arg:
      - code

set_grains:
  local.grains.setvals:
    - tgt: {{ minion_id }}
    - arg:
      - {"code":"2","code_ename":"tt"}


At this point, I am not sure how to proceed. It seems that SaltStack does not have a direct method to pass the result of one task to the next task, similar to how Ansible registers variables.
How can I achieve my goal of setting grains attributes by retrieving the code variable from the minion's pillar data? Or is there a better approach to achieve this?

Your code does not show any attempt to set the grain based on pillar data.

What are you trying to achieve by setting pillar data back into grains? I think helps to conceptually think about the data loading in the order of grains -> pillar -> local state variables.

although technically there can be loops where states set new grains and pillar (and I would suggest avoiding doing that as much as possible).


How can I achieve my goal of setting grains attributes by retrieving the code variable from the minion's pillar data?

This can be done with a simple state:
code:
  grains.present:
   - value: {{ pillar['code'] }}

code_ename:
  grains.present:
   - value: {{ pillar['code_ename'] }}

You can apply that via a reactor, or just have it be part of the minion's highstate and/or startup_states.
!! N.B. This stores the grain in /etc/salt/grains, which by default is world-readable. The secret data in your pillar (because that is what pillar is for) will be exposed to all processes on the minion unless you e.g. include this state:
/etc/salt/grains:
  file.managed:
    - replace: false
    - mode: '0600'
    - require_in:
      - grains: '*'


Or is there a better approach to achieve this?

If the grain is just the same value as the pillar, there's no point copying it to a grain. Just use the pillar directly.
